# Namenode failure and recovery in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

How does Hadoop determine that the Namenode has failed or is not working?

I know that in Hadoop the Namenode is the main point which keeps all the metadata, recognizes the failure of datanodes by heartbeats, and opts for replication of data in case of datanode failure.

If the Namenode fails, which system recognizes the failure, and what is the recovery process?

Comment: This article gave me a good idea about Namenode failure & high availability.. https://data-flair.training/blogs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-high-availability/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends which version of Hadoop you are talking about. Before Hadoop 2, the `Namenode` was a single point of failure, so if it failed that meant your cluster became unusable. Even the `SecondaryNameNode` doesn't help in that case since it's only used for checkpoints, not as a backup for the `NameNode`. When the `NameNode` fails, someone like an administrator would have to manually restart the `NameNode`.

But since Hadoop 2, you have a better way to handle failures in the `NameNode`. You can run 2 redundant `NameNodes` alongside one another, so that if one of the `Namenodes` fails, the cluster will quickly failover to the other `NameNode`.

The way it works is pretty transparent, basically the `DataNodes` will send reports to both `NameNodes` so that if one fails, the other one will be ready to be used in active mode. And for the client, it simply contacts every `NameNode` configured until it finds the active one. So if it gets a reply saying to try elsewhere, or if the `NameNode` doesn't reply, it knows that it needs to use a different `NameNode`.

Here is a schema taken from [the Cloudera blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/) which explains that in more details:

[image: HANN]

You can also take a look at [the HA article on the official documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html) on how to set this up.

Comment: What happens if both of them failed

Comment: The URL http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html doesn't work anymore

Comment: @charles
We also have the QJM concept which involves Zookeeper, where there is a lock under the primary name node and every time the secondary name node tries to fetch the key, only the secondary name node/stand by name node can fetch the key as the primary node fails.

How do these things work together?

Comment: If Active and Passive both name nodes goes down, we can leverage secondary namenode to retrieve data.